# Is the cardinality of the real numbers $\mathfrak{c}$ a real number?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, real-numbers, cardinals, infinity

This may be a stupid question, but I was learning some set and group theory and it just made me think. Clearly the continuum is an infinite quantity $\mathfrak{c}$, but the set of all reals is also infinitely long. Or is it that $\sup(\mathbb{R})=\mathfrak{c}$ and $\mathfrak{c}\notin\mathbb{R}$. Regardless this is a theoretical question, but if someone who likes set theory could help me out it'd be very appreciated!

Comment: The infinity that is at the "top" of the real number line (commonly called $\infty$) is, if these things can be compared at all, distinctly smaller than the continuum.

Comment: Vsauce's popular [How to count past infinity](https://youtu.be/SrU9YDoXE88) may help you understand exactly what cardinals (and ordinals) are.

Comment: Numbers are used for different purposes, and while the differences may be glossed over for finite numbers, they become apparent when talking about infinite quantities. Using number to answer the question "how many?", and using it to answer the question "how far along the line?", have much in common, but they're fundamentally different.

Comment: You might also consider: if $\mathfrak c$ were on the number line somewhere, then where would you find  $\aleph_0$, which is strictly smaller?

Comment: $\mathfrak{c}$ is a *cardinal number* which is not what real numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a real number r, of real numbers.
Clearly there is a positive number of real numbers.
Also the number of real numbers is not fractional.
So r has to be a positive integer.

Let R be the set of all r real numbers.
Since r is finite, R has a maximum m.
Since m + 1 is not in R, a contradiction ensues.
Thus there is not a real number of real numbers.

Hence there be an unreal number of real numbres.

Answer (score 1):

No.  But the first uncountable *ordinal*, $\omega_1$, does lie on the [long line](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))...